# for loop conversion from C to Python

Tags: python, for-loop

How can I write the `for` loop in Python as I write it in C:

```
for(i=0;i<10;)
{
    if(i%2==0)
       i=i+3;
    else
       i++;
    printf("%d\n",i);
}
```

Can anyone tell me about this? I searched a lot but couldn't find it. I wrote it like this in Python:

```
for i in range(0,10):
    if (i%2==0):
        i+=3
    else:
        i+=1
    print i
```

Output:

```
3
2
5
4
7
6
9
8
11
10
```

Expected output:

```
3
4
7
8
11
```

Can anyone also explain the reason of this output?

Comment: What output were you expecting?

Comment: the output looks fine

Comment: As i new to python I can't understand the output, please explain it to me @Ajay

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To write the same loop in Python:

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    if i % 2 == 0:
       i += 3
    else:
       i += 1
    print i
```

Which gives:

```
3
4
7
8
11
```

Note that, per [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements):

> The `for` statement in Python differs a bit from what you may be used to
>   in C or Pascal. Rather than always iterating over an arithmetic
>   progression of numbers (like in Pascal), or giving the user the
>   ability to define both the iteration step and halting condition (as
>   C), Python’s `for` statement iterates over the items of any sequence (a
>   list or a string), in the order that they appear in the sequence.

In a Python `for` loop, any changes to the loop variable (`i`, in this case) that occur during the loop are ignored when the loop repeats, and the next value from the object being iterated over is used. In this case, the object is a list of numbers:

```
>>> range(10)  # note that a 0 start is the default
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Some languages call this a `for each` loop. See also [the language reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) for more details.

Comment: I understood everything @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 2):

`range(0, 10)` function returns list of values from 0 to 9:

`range(0, 10) == [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Then `for` body is executed for each element in this list.
If You have 0, the 0 % 2 == 0 so it prints 0 + 3 etc.
In C You changed `i` value so You jumped to other value in set. Using python's `for` You will get through all elements. You should use

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
  if (i % 2 == 0):
    i += 3
  else:
    i += 1
  print i
```

To have same results as in `C`

Comment: thanks for the explanation, actually I forget the way python works, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for i in range(10):
    if i%2 == 0:
        i = i+3
    else:
        i = i + 1
    print i
```

it gives the same output u asked for...hope this helps

Comment: where is the initialization?

Comment: why we can't set the steps when we use range(0,10), why we have to specifically use range(10)?

Comment: we can by range(0,10,step) but the step cannot be 0 so it wont satisfy what you wanted to achieve